# Inquirer.js input answer is exiting process when hitting enter

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I have recently started making a CLI (Command line interface) with the NPM package; Inquirer, it is a very helpful module but I have run into a problem. The interface while works as should cannot get to the main code because after the user hits enter after they have typed input to the question the process exits even though there is still code to execute and so far everything I have tried does not work.

-- *Thank you in advance*

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a specific answer without seeing the code, but after your prompt do you include `.then`?

Inside that `.then` promise you will pass a function with the parameter that will be the response from inquirer.  For example I may say:

```html
Inquirer.prompt([
        {
            type: "list",
            name: "activity",
            message: "What would you like to do?",
            choices: ["Create new cards", "Delete old cards", "Organize packs", "Practice with current cards"]
        }
    ]).then(function(inqResp){
        var activity = inqResp.activity;

        if (activity === "Create new cards"){
            createMenu();
        } else if (activity === "Delete old cards"){
            deleteMenu();
        } else if (activity === "Organize packs"){
            packsMenu();
        } else if (activity === "Practice with current cards"){
            practiceMenu();
        }
    });
```

This code will ask the use to select an action then it will reference their choice as `inqResp.activity` because that is what I named it.  That then needs to call the next code you want to run.  In my case it is another function.  In yours it may be that you want to do something with their response.